# If end date is empty show "Now" or "Current" or something else

Tags: 7, theming, datetime

In some of the content type I have a field date with collects start date and end date.
The end date is not required and is empty as default value.

When I show date in teaser or node or view it will show start and end date but I want a condition

```
if (empty($end_date)) {
 print "current";
} else {
print $end_date;
}
```

of course I can set it in the node.tpl.php, for the teaser and the node, and with alternative text if empty in the views with field setting.

Now would like to know if there is any way to do it with the API. Something I can do in the template.php and not in every single node--CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php and in every single view.

I'm looking for something like

```
function my_module_date_api ($something) {
if (empty($end_date)) {
     print "current";
    } else {
    print $end_date;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Custom Formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters/) module.

"The Custom Formatters module allows users to easily create custom CCK/Field Formatters without the need to write a custom module."

Comment: Westie, I've tested it but I would prefer to use the old way through the tpl.php file. Do you know which API should I call?

Comment: Well you can do this is two ways, either a preprocessor hook (like template_preprocess_field) in your template.php before the data comes into the tpl.php or in the tpl.php itself.

Comment: sorry, that was half comment. I will try this function. Thanks

Comment: Hi Westie,
I've put this piece of code
function bartik_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == field_date) {
 
}
} 

now this error comes up
Use of undefined constant field_date - assumed 'field_date' in bartik_preprocess_field()

Comment: try 'field_date' otherwise php is looking for a constant rather than a value

Comment: Thanks Westie, I prefer the preprocess_field() approach, It look like I've got more freedom. Thanks for your help!